# How to hide categories in a piechart that have no data in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a program that takes a user input and counts the instances of each letter used in the input, and then turns it into a piechart. However, I only want the letters used in the input to be displayed, and hide all other letters. This is what I have now, that results in all the letters appearing in the legend, even if they are 0%.

```
list1 = []
answer = str(input('Please describe your thoughts on cats in a couple sentences:'))
list1.extend(answer)
print(list1)
labels = (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
''' need to count instances of each letter, number, or symbol used'''
a = list1.count('a')
b = list1.count('b')
c = list1.count('c')
d = list1.count('d')
e = list1.count('e')
f = list1.count('f')
g = list1.count('g')
h = list1.count('h')
i = list1.count('i')
j = list1.count('j')
k = list1.count('k')
l = list1.count('l')
m = list1.count('m')
n = list1.count('n')
o = list1.count('o')
p = list1.count('p')
q = list1.count('q')
r = list1.count('r')
s = list1.count('s')
t = list1.count('t')
u = list1.count('u')
v = list1.count('v')
w = list1.count('w')
x = list1.count('x')
y = list1.count('y')
z = list1.count('z')
'''numbers and symbols also need to be calculated to take away from final total'''
one = list1.count('1')
two = list1.count('2')
three = list1.count('3')
four = list1.count('4')
five = list1.count('5')
six = list1.count('6')
seven = list1.count('7')
eight = list1.count('8')
nine = list1.count('9')
period = list1.count('.')
exclamation = list1.count('!')
question = list1.count('?')
comma = list1.count(',')
space = list1.count(' ')
apostraphe = list1.count("'")
pie = (len(list1) - one - two - three - four - five - six - seven - eight - nine - period - exclamation - question - comma - space - apostraphe)
size = [(a/pie)*100, (b/pie)*100, (c/pie)*100, (d/pie)*100, (e/pie)*100, (f/pie)*100, (g/pie)*100, (h/pie)*100, (i/pie)*100, (j/pie)*100, (k/pie)*100, (l/pie)*100, (m/pie)*100, (n/pie)*100, (o/pie)*100, (p/pie)*100, (q/pie)*100, (r/pie)*100, (s/pie)*100, (t/pie)*100, (u/pie)*100, (v/pie)*100, (w/pie)*100, (x/pie)*100, (y/pie)*100, (z/pie)*100] # one/pie, two/pie, three/pie, four/pie, five/pie, six/pie, seven/pie, eight/pie, nine/pie, period/pie, exclamation/pie, question/pie, comma/pie, space/pie]
# fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'springgreen', 'moccasin', 'mediumslateblue', 'teal', 'maroon', 'salmon', 'yellowgreen', 'dodgerblue', 'pink', 'deeppink', 'plum', 'grey', 'white', 'black', 'wheat', 'slategrey', 'gold', 'aqua', 'indigo', 'chartreuse']
plt.pie(size, colors=colors, normalize = True, startangle = 90)
labels = ['%s, %1.1f %%' % (l, s) for l, s in zip(labels, size)]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.legend(loc='best', labels=labels)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("Number of instances of each character in user input")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your labels for your legend, instead of using the lines:

```py
labels = ['%s, %1.1f %%' % (l, s) for l, s in zip(labels, size)]
plt.legend(loc='best', labels=labels)
```

you could use:

```py
labels_plot = []
for l,s in zip(labels, size):
    if s>0.:
        labels_plot.append('%s, %1.1f %%' % (l, s))
    else: 
        labels_plot.append('_nolegend_')
plt.legend(loc='best', labels=labels_plot)
```

This will discard the letters with a frequency of 0% from the legend.
Below is an example of the output of the code for the word "stackoverflow":

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. However now my graph is showing spaces and other symbols and it shows up as a blank part (even though I have normalize = True). I had put earlier in my code to not count those instances so I am not sure what is causing this. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to see what's wrong with your code without seeing an example (code and output) of what you are describing. If you think your issue is unrelated to the legend maybe start a new question on SO.